# Android build gradle dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, build, dependencies

I have an app with 2 libraries as dependencies. I'm trying to build a script that clones those libraries into an empty folder and build the project.

I created a task within the app's build.gradle that clones the repos:
exec { commandLine "git", "clone", repo, repoFolderName }

The script starts and clones the repos, all fine but when it starts building the app if fails with the following error:
"Could not determine the dependencies of task ..."

If I run the script again it will successfully build the project.

From my initial investigation it seems that Gradle creates the dependencies as the 1st thing, before the libraries are locally cloned so the libraries are not there hence the build fails. If I run it again as the libraries are already there it will successfully build the project.

Any help is much appreciated.